# How do I set the certificate for k8s to more than 1 year?

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I'm a novice k8s engineer.
Until now, I have managed the k8s certificate by manually renewing it once a year.

However, I became curious about how to set the certificates below for more than 1 year in the first place.

```
[root@master ~]# kubeadm alpha certs check-expiration

CERTIFICATE                EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
admin.conf                 May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
apiserver                  May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
apiserver-etcd-client      May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
apiserver-kubelet-client   May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
controller-manager.conf    May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
etcd-healthcheck-client    May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
etcd-peer                  May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
etcd-server                May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
front-proxy-client         May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no      
scheduler.conf             May 21, 2022 01:29 UTC   311d            no
```

Can these certificates be extended by more than a year? (nearly 10 years..?)

k8s version is 1.16

I can use a private certificate. It doesn't matter which way.
(There is a limit to searching because I am not good at English.)

Please tell me how to renew the K8s certificate(api..) only once every 10 years!

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to have the certificates for more than one year. Kubernetes provides hassle-free way to create and renew certs every one year.
[Kubernetes Certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/)
Since you need it for some special requirement:

- Check certs expiration
- Back up the existing Kubernetes certificates. Backup all the certs in
  the pki dir to somewhere safe and controlled access.
- Backup the existing and necessary configurtion files
- Add --cluster-signing-duration flag for kube-controller-manager. [kubernetes doc for signing duration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/certificate-rotation/)

Edit /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
  ...
   name: kube-controller-manager
   namespace: kube-system
 spec:
   containers:
   - command:
     - kube-controller-manager
     ...
     - --experimental-cluster-signing-duration=87600h
     ...
 ...
```

87600h ~ 10 years

- Renew all certs kubeadm alpha certs renew all --config
  /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml
- Follow the CSR request and approve method.
- Restart the necessary componenets like etcd, kube-apiserver, kube-scheduler , controller, kubelet
- Check the new cert expiry

Please follow this in the test lab scenario before doing on any prod envs while the clusters are running